# adding a list of string in javascript asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a javascript in my page which requires a string list in this format:

```
var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
```

My model in the view contains a list of string named blogtags.
How do I add the list in the viewmodel to the javascript.

Thanks
Arnab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a string type to hold a comma seperated tags to my viewmodel

```
public class BlogPostViewModel
{
  //Other properties    
  public string Tags { set;get;}    
}
```

In my controll, I will set the value of this from the List of string

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
  var vm=new BlogPostViewModel();

  List<string> tagList=new List<string>(); 
  tagList.Add("PERL");   //get from your DB instead of hardcoding
  tagList.Add("RUBY");

  StringBuilder strTags = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var item in tagList)
  {
     strTags.Append("\""+item+"\",");
  }
  vm.Tags=strTags.ToString();
  vm.Tags= vm.Tags.TrimEnd(','); //remove last ,
  return View(vm);
}
```

And in the View

```
$(function () {    
  var items=[@Html.Raw(Model.Tags)]
  alert(items);
});
```

Comment: the result is  var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","asp","php",]
I need to get rid of the last ','- tx

Comment: @Shyju not really good approach for joining several string to one. you can use the following code instead: vm.Tags = string.Join(",", tagList);

Comment: in this specific case, it needs the \ char. So straight forward string.join won't help.